# Issue with jquery tools overlay in Safari

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, overlay, jquery-tools

I am trying to present a form inside an overlay. The form is loaded via ajax. This all works fine on firefox 3.x.

But on Safari 5.0(5533.16), the overlay shows but does not make an ajax request, rather makes a html request.

Here is how I configure it in my js and then on document.ready I call ModalPostForm.init();

pastie  - http://pastie.org/1196064

```
var ModalPostForm = {
    init: function(){
        $("a[rel='#post_overlay']").each(function(){
            //alert($(this).attr('href'));
            $(this).overlay({
                closeOnClick: false,
                target: '#post_overlay',
                fixed: false,
                onBeforeLoad: function() {
                    // grab wrapper element inside content
                    var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
                    // load the page specified in the trigger
                    wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
                },
                onLoad: function() {
                    setTimeout("configurePostForm(200, 1000, 150)", 500);
                },
                onClose: function() {
                    $('.contentWrap').empty();
                }
            });
        });
    },

    close: function(){
        $("a[rel='#post_overlay']").each(function(){
            var ol = $(this).data("overlay");
            if(ol.isOpened()){
                ol.close();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Here is my html

```
<div id="post_overlay" class="new-post-overlay span-12" style="top: 54.3px; left: 429px; position: absolute; display: none;"><a class="close"></a>
  <div style="display: none;" id="form_loading" class="">
    <div class="loading-inner-center"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="" class="contentWrap"></div>
</div>
```

Why is it issuing html request?

Thanks

### UPDATE

This goes away if I remove the format.html block in my rails respond_to block in my controller actions.

Though the question remains why it it sending a html request or why rails thinks it is a html request. I would rather not remove that block, for browsers that indeed can't do js.

### new action which causes the issue

```
        respond_to do |format|
#            format.html # new.html.erb
            format.js {

            }
#            format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
        end
```

### edit action which also causes the issue, both new and edit happen to be 'get' methods.

```
#            format.html {
#                if @edit
#                    #
#                    setup_post_items(true)
#                else
#                    flash[:error] = 'Sorry no further edits, Post has already been approved.'
#                    redirect_back_or_default root_url
#                end
#            }
            format.js {
                if !@edit
                    flash[:error] = 'Sorry no further edits, Post has already been approved.'
                end
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've also noticed that the format.html block sometimes catches js requests. There are two methods I've used to work around this issue (either of the following should fix it, you don't need to do both):

a) In your javascript, append ".js" to your target href. For instance:

```
if ( ! /\.js/.test($this.attr('href')) ) {
  $this.attr('href', function(index, href) {
    return href.replace(/([^\?]+)(.*)/, '$1.js$2');
  });
}
```

b) In your controller, put the format.js block *before* the format.html block so that the javascript request matches the js block before it matches the html block.